# Using variables in BigQuery view definition

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a simple query that runs successfully, but when I introduce a variable into the query, I am unable to save a view using that query. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE color = 'red';
```

This query runs fine. Then:

```
DECLARE color STRING DEFAULT 'red';
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE color = color;
```

This query also runs fine. Then in the BigQuery UI I click to "Save view", but I get an error saying Unexpected keyword DECLARE. Why is that?

Comment: Views are static, so I'm not sure why you want to use a variable in a view (as Gordon points out, this is not possible) but a stored procedure might be more in line with what you are trying to do: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/command-and-control-now-easier-in-bigquery-with-scripting-and-stored-procedures

Comment: @NathanGriffiths the query I gave is just an example. In reality I need to reference the color `red` in a few places throughout the query, so I thought using a variable would allow me to edit it in one place in case it ever needs to change.

Comment: If you think the value of color might change over time then a better approach could be to create a stored procedure that accepts color as a parameter and then executes your query.

Answer (score 3):

As explained in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views):

> BigQuery views are subject to the following limitations:
>
> - You cannot reference query parameters in views.

What you want to do is not allowed.  A view is limited to a single `SELECT` statement.