# How to use variable in view definition in Postgres/plpgsql

Tags: sql, postgresql, view, plpgsql

I am using plpgsql with Postgres 10.6.  I have a function that declares and gives value to a variable.  That function also defines a view, and I would like to use the variable within the definition.

```
  create view myview as
    select
      some_columns
    from
      mytable
    where      
      id = _id     /*_id is declared earlier in function */
  ;
```

In this case, the function can be defined, but when it is run it gives an error: `UndefinedColumn: column "_id" does not exist`

**Is such a thing possible in Postgres?  Can views include variables as part of their definition?**

I do see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59759297/using-variables-in-bigquery-view-definition) that in BigQuery (which I have never used), what I am asking is not possible, which makes me think it may also not be possible in plpgsql.

It is not a big deal, but I am curious.  A workaround - and probably the recommended solution - is to pass the _id when I select from the view (e.g. `select * from myview where id = 3`).  Or, if I really want to keep the select call simple (which I do, because my actual implementation is more complicated and has multiple variables), I could define the view as a string and use `execute` within the function (this is all internal stuff used in building up and creating a db, not in a situation where the various risks inherent to dynamic sql are a concern).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can not pass a variable to a view. But you can do this with a function:

```
create function my_view_function(p_id integer)
  returns table (id int, column_1 int, column2 text)
as
$$
  select id, column_1, column_2
  from my_table
  where id = p_id;
$$
language sql
stable;
```

Then use it like this

```
select *
from my_view_function(42);
```

Comment: Thanks for the definitive "no, you cannot pass a variable to a view" answer.  Also, your solution is a good solution to accomplish what I am trying to do.  Thank you.